# SQL Three table join

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I haven't been able to solve this problem for several days now and I'm hoping you can help.

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the information about a stock and the last time it was updated. I would like to filter the results based on the parameter @date and return only the stocks which it's latests update is less than the supplied @date parameter. I also need the stocks with a timestamp of null so I know that theses stocks need to be updated.  I have the follwing three tables that I'm working with:

```
stocks
- id
- asset_id
- market_id
- name
- symbol
- IPOYear
- sector
- industry

updates
- id
- [timestamp]

stock_updates
- stock_id
- update_id
```

I've been using the following query and it was working well for me until I realized it dosen't work if the stock doesn't have an update

```
select * from stocks s
where @date < (
    select top 1 u.timestamp from
        updates u,
        stock_updates su
    where
        s.id = su.stock_id and
        u.id = su.update_id
    order by u.timestamp desc
)
```

So after some research I came accross outer joins and I think it's what I need to fix my problem I just haven't been able to construct the correct query. The closest I've come is the following, but it returns a record for each time the stock was updated. Thanks in advance for your help!

This is where I'm at now:

```
select * from stocks s 
left outer join stock_updates su on s.id = su.stock_id 
left outer join updates u on u.id = su.update_id 
where u.[timestamp] < @date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select s.*, u.timestamp
from stocks s 
left join 
(select  su.stock_id, MAX(u.timestamp) timestamp
from updates u 
inner join stock_updates su 
on u.id = su.update_id
group by su.stock_id
) as u
on s.id = u.stock_id
where u.[timestamp] is null or u.[timestamp] < @date
```

Comment: Thank you @jbrooks for responding! This almost works and does exactly what I asked in the question, it will return all the stocks with their latest timestamp including if the timestamp is null. However I neglected to add in the question that I need to add the date parameter to select only the stocks that haven't been updated from the date passed. When I uncommented the WHERE clause, I got an error so I moved it after the "s.id = u.stock_id" and it returned all the stocks with their latest timestamp update but only if they had a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT s.*, v.timestamp
FROM stocks s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(u.timestamp) AS timestamp, su.stock_id
    FROM stock_updates su
    INNER JOIN updates u ON (u.id = su.update_id)
    GROUP BY su.stock_id
) v ON (v.stock_id = s.stock_id)
```

Basically it just joins the `stocks` table to an "inline view" that is the result of a query to determine the maximum `timestamp` for each `stock_id`.

Comment: @Yuck: ...and completely unecessary. I'm assuming they have created it by mistake.

Comment: @MitchWheat Haha I did the same.

Comment: Thanks @ninesided. This works exactly as I described but I need to add a WHERE clause to this that I forgot to put into the question. I'm looking for a dataset that would return all the stocks that haven't been updated by the supplied date. However, I also need to include the stocks that have a null timestamp. Thanks for your help! robokop 10 mins ago

Comment: Thanks @ninesided, works perfectly when I added the WHERE clause!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't included any filtering by the `@date` parameter, as your question states

> "I'm trying to write a query that returns all the information about a
>   stock and the last time it was updated"

and for that you don't require any filtering.

This query does exactly that:

```
select s.*, dr.maxtime,  
from stocks s  
left join (select MAX(u.timestamp) as maxtime, su.stock_id 
           from stock_updates su inner join updates u on u.id = su.update_id
           group by su.stock_id) dr
    on dr.stock_id = s.stock_id
where 
   maxtime < @date or maxtime is null
```

[BTW: `left join` is the same as `left outer join`]

Comment: I was going to add it BUT rereading the question poster says "I'm trying to write a query that returns all the information about a stock and the last time it was updated".

Comment: This is the trouble with these hit-and-run questions - no clarification from the OP, lots of correct solutions, and no one sees anything for their effort. What a waste. =/

Comment: Thanks @MitchWheat Wheat. This works exactly as I originally described but I need to add a WHERE clause that will return only the stocks that who's last update is before the supplied date parameter. When I add the WHERE dr.maxtime < date after on dr.stock_id = s.stock_id it filters correctly but doesn't include the stocks with a timestamp of null. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks @MitchWheat! Works perfectly when I add the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select s.*, max(su.timestamp)
from
    stocks s
        left outer join
    stock_update su
        on (s.id = su.stock_id)
        left outer join
    updates u
        on (u.id = su.update_id)
group by s.*
```

It's written off the top of my head. What do you refer to with `@date`? Does that mean "now"? Do you mean the latest timestamp, or the latest before `@date`?